# Окно pygame не отвечает сразу после запуска

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Сразу же после появления окна, оно перестаёт отвечать. Задний фон вместо изображения залит серым. Весь инет перерыл, уже не знаю где искать.

Вот код:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
background_image = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/и/Desktop/проект/image/space.jpg')
while True:
    pygame.event.get()
    screen.blit(background_image,(0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)
```

Comment: У меня та же проблема! Я уже думал над тем, чтобы сносить винду! Помогите пожалуйста с неактивным и серым окном... У меня и в клиенте покер старс та же проблема... первый раз после холодного запуска открываю стол, всё нормально, закрываю, открываю следующий - виснет и серым становится, приходится перезапускать клиент. Я думал это проблема с клиентом, а теперь ещё и в Python та же проблема...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

font = pygame.font.SysFont("Helvetica", 48)
background_image = font.render("Hello World!!", 1, (255,0,0), (0,0,255))
x = 0
y = 0
kontrol = True

#pygame.image.load('C:/Users/и/Desktop/проект/image/space.jpg')
pygame.image.load('ball.png')

while True:
    clock.tick(30)
#    pygame.event.get()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))                      # :)

#    screen.blit(background_image,(0,0))    
    if(kontrol):
        screen.blit(background_image, (x, 0))
        x += 10
        if(x == 600):
            kontrol = False 

    if(not kontrol):
        screen.blit(background_image, (x, 0))
        x -= 10
        if(x == 0):
            kontrol = True

    pygame.display.update()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

или так:

```
import pygame,sys

pygame.init()
boyut = (800, 600)

ball = pygame.image.load("Ok.png")

font = pygame.font.SysFont("Helvetica", 48)
mertmekatronik = font.render("Mert Mekatronik", 1, (255,0,0), (255,255,255))

topX = ball.get_size()[0]
topY = ball.get_size()[1]

pencere = pygame.display.set_mode(boyut)

x = 0
y = 0

xYON = 1
yYON = 1

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    clock.tick(50)  
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:sys.exit()

    pencere.fill((255, 255, 255))

    if x > 800 - topX or x < 0:
        xYON *= -1

    if y > 600 - topY or y < 0:
        yYON *= -1

    x += 10 * xYON                                   
    y += 10 * yYON

    pencere.blit(ball,(x,y))
    pygame.display.update()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

```
import sys
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((660,620))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#background_image = 
#pygame.image.load('C:/Users/и/Desktop/проект/image/space.jpg')
image  = pygame.image.load("im.png")            
rect   = image.get_rect()

while True:
    clock.tick(30)
#    pygame.event.get()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

#    screen.blit(background_image,(0,0))
    screen.blit(image, rect)

    pygame.display.update()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо конечно ,но это немного не то ,что мне нужно. Я хотел бы узнать почему у меня не отвечает окно и как мне это исправить так как мне нужно окно со своим изображением, а не анимацией текста.

Comment: @SosiscasViscas я добавил пример, попробуйте.

Comment: спасибо большое ,всё работает.

Comment: @SosiscasViscas если мой ответ решил вашу проблему, не забывайте отметить его как правильный.